# How do I store and call 500k images?

Tags: php, mysql

I have 500k unique images in my folder/directory. I want call it by name and all names are stored in Mysql database. but I heard that images can be stored in a database. So my question is which is more fastest option to display image faster. do I need to store in mySQl or can I keep same method which I am following?

If I need to store in mySQL then how do I create a table for it, and how do I store all these images?

Comment: how do you think yourself which is faster? Just by comparing operations, required to display an image

Comment: Don't store all 500k images in a single directory... have 100 subdirectories holding 5k images each.

Comment: @Mark Baker I am interested if you got benchmarks to proof your statement?

Comment: @Alfred - I've never benchmarked, and plucked the figures 100 and 5k out of the top of my head. However, the principles behind reduced performance of very large directories are well known, as is the solution. sarnold has given a better explanation in his answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has been answered quite a few times. But you haven't talked about what type of application that you are building, if you are building a web application then storing the images on the file system has advantages re: caching.

[Storing Images In Filesystem As Files Or In BLOB Database Field As Binaries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262646/storing-images-in-filesystem-as-files-or-in-blob-database-field-as-binaries)

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

It's easy enough to store the images in a table, I would definitely avoid it though if your images are quite large.

Answer (score 4):

I do not think 500k entries in a single directory will go over very well: [How many files can I put in a directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many)

Once upon a time, Linux ext3 started running slowly for very simple operations once a directory accumulated around 2000 files. (O(N) sorts of slowly!) After the [htree](http://lwn.net/Articles/11481/) patches were merged, large directory performance improved drastically, but I'd still recommend partitioning your image store based on some very easy criteria. (Squid web cache, for example, creates directory trees like `01/`, `02/`, and places files based on the first two characters in the filename.)

Answer (score 3):

Do not store so many data in a db like mysql especially if you are not so familiar like you sound. Keep the images on the fs

Answer (score 2):

> I have 500k unique images in my
>   folder/directory. I want call it by
>   name and all names are stored in Mysql
>   database. but I heard that images can
>   be store in database. so my question
>   is which is more fastest option to
>   display image faster.

You should use the file system. Storing in database is not going to work very well. You should read [Facebook Photo Storage Architecture](http://www.niallkennedy.com/blog/2009/04/facebook-haystack.html) to learn how [facebook](http://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919&ref=mf) does it. They have the most photos in the world.

**Haystack file storage:**

[image]

Also interesting:
http://www.fredberinger.com/high-performance-at-massive-scale-lessons-learned-at-facebook/

Comment: I don't think that the OP has access to a system the size of the FBCDN.

Comment: probably not, but the point is the are using the file system instead of MySQL database. It is also a very interesting read in my humble opinion :P

Answer (score 1):

Storing images into the database (in a blob datatype) in much more inefficient than keep those images stored on the file system.

BTW [here](http://forum.codecall.net/php-tutorials/6937-tutorial-storing-images-mysql-php.html) is explained how to insert binary data into a mysql table

Answer (score 0):

If you have Redis, you could put all the images in memory, that would be the quickest way